# How to use array keys as new values for a derived array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array which I would like to edit:

```
Array
(
    [qty_black_34] => 
    [qty_black_36] => 2
    [qty_black_38] => 
    [qty_black_40] => 
    [qty_black_42] => 
    [qty_black_44] => 
    [qty_black_48] => 
    [qty_powder_34] => 
    [qty_powder_36] => 
    [qty_powder_38] => 
    [qty_powder_40] => 
    [qty_powder_42] => 1
    [qty_powder_44] => 
    [qty_powder_48] => 
    [qty_red_34] => 
    [qty_red_36] => 
    [qty_red_38] => 2
    [qty_red_40] => 
    [qty_red_42] => 
    [qty_red_44] => 
    [qty_red_48] => )
```

What I want to do is to build another array to hold only the elements with a value. 
The new array must look like this"

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [color] => black
                [size] => 36
                [quantity] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [color] => powder
                [size] => 42
                [quantity] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [color] => red
                [size] => 38
                [quantity] => 2
            )

    )
```

PHP is the language I'm using.

Comment: Okay, but what is your question?

Comment: 'What I want to do is to build another array to hold only the elements with a value' sounds like the/a question to me... True, it could been put in a more question-like form, but still

Comment: Pekka, the question is how can I build the second array.

Comment: @stereofrog, strictly speaking yes, but with a bit of imagination one could think that the OP is asking for tha codez, as that seems to be the major subject of this Q&A site. Whether that is a good question (as there is no evidence of failed tries) is another story (of which I believe the answer is no)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

loop through array and take elements, which have set a value. for the additional key/values in your final array split the string used as key in original array

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $key => value) {
    if ($value) {
        $key_split = explode('_', $key);
        $new_array[] = array('color' => $key_split[1], 'size' => $key_split[2], 'quantity' => $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$products = array();
foreach($quantities as $key => $quantity){
    if($quantity != '') {
        list($q, $color, $size) = explode('_', $key);
        $products[] = array(
            'color' => $color,
            'size' => $size,
            'quantity' => $quantity
        );
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/KNbiTp2F)